# clear mutiple textboxes by reusing an event handler

Tags: c#

I have 3 textboxes and I need to clear the text once the text box is clicked.
The only thing is that I have to do that by reusing the same event handler. I created the event handler, gave it a general name to fit all, but now I don't know what statement to write inside it. 
if I write : `txtBox1.Clear();` it will only clear that one textbox, but if I write: `txtBox1.Clear(); txtBox2.Clear(); txtBox3.Clear();` 
It will clear all of them when only one is clicked.
In other words, I need it to clear only the text of the textbox that has been clicked, but they all have to be under the same event handler.
Anything will help! thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can assign the same event handler to all the textBoxes and use `sender` parameter to get the real sender.

```
private void textBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        textBox.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: @LeaMay: Do not thak here... accept the answer by the tick, you will thank like that... Welcome to SO, by the way.